# Read integers from .obj file in c++

Tags: c++, file, object-files

I have following problem. I need read integers from file xxx.obj. Integers are always 4B.

If i use hexdump -C to file, it looks:

```
04 00 00 00 06 00 00 00  08 00 00 00 50 00 00 00
```

One pair is 1B.

This is, how i open file:

```
ifstream fs1;
fs1.open( srcFile1, ios::in | ios::binary );
```

This is, how i read 1B from file in loop:

```
while( fs1.get( c ) )
  {
    cnt = (int)(unsigned char)c;
    cout << cnt << endl;

  }
```

Out is:

```
4
0
0
0
6
0
0
0
8
0
0
0
80
0
0
0
```

Any idea how to read directly int or how to read 4x 1B and then convert to int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `int32_t` data type so you can be sure of getting a 4-byte int. Or use `uint32-t` if you want unsigned numbers.

```
int32_t x; // Make sure integer is 4 bytes
fs1.read(&x, sizeof(x)); // Read from file
```

Comment: @Levin That makes sense. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
int val;
while(fs)
{
     fs.read(&val, sizeof(val);
     if(fs) cout<<val<<endl
}
```

The function read of a stream allows to read an arbitrary chunk of data at once and copy it into a zone of memory.

The code above read chunks of size of `int` at once and copy them into the memory zone of an int - `val`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.